# haystack: How to limit SearchQuerySet to a single SearchIndex?

Tags: django, django-haystack

Context:
[`SearchIndex`](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchindex_api.html#SearchIndex) is analogous to django's `Model`. It is even tied to a single model via `get_model`.
[`SearchQuerySet`](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html#SearchQuerySet) is analogous to django's `QuerySet` (except the way of obtaining an instance).
[`HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS`](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/multiple_index.html#multiple-indexes) are analogous to django's `DATABASES`.

One not immediately apparent difference is that performing `SearchQuerySet` operations uses ALL `SearchIndex` subclasses you have.
How to perform operations on a single SearchIndex (for a single model) only? Connections don't seem to be meant for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SearchQuerySet.models`](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html#models) is the answer, buried deep in the docs.
Add `.models(DjangoModel1, DjangoModel2)` to your SearchQuerySet calls, where the models are those returned by your chosen `SearchIndex`es' `get_model`.